# Javascript Delete First Character on Each Line of String

Tags: javascript

I need to remove the first character of a string "|" on each line in javascript.

```
| D| Gbm| G| A|
| D| Gbm| G| A|
| Bm| Gbm| G| D|
| Bm| Gbm| G| A|
| D| Gbm| G| A|
| D| Gbm| G| A|
| Bm| Gbm| G| D|
| Bm| E| G| G A|
| D| Gbm|
```

end results needed:

```
 D| Gbm| G| A|
 D| Gbm| G| A|
 Bm| Gbm| G| D|
 Bm| Gbm| G| A|
 D| Gbm| G| A|
 D| Gbm| G| A|
 Bm| Gbm| G| D|
 Bm| E| G| G A|
 D| Gbm|
```

This is the page I need to edit to get just the chords.
I removed the quotes with

```
tOut = tOut.replace("\"", "");
```

http://www.lesession.co.uk/abc/abcChordsOut.htm
This is the text input in ABC Notation format:

```
X:1
T:Guitar
L:1/8
K:D  
Q:1/4=120
R:Medium Boogie 
M:4/4
| "D"D,2 A,,D, D,2 [C,A,,]_B,,/2=B,,/2 | "Gbm"_G,,3 _G,,/2E,,/2 _G,,2 _D,/2=D,/2_E,/2=E,/2 | "G"G,3 G, G,3 =G,, | "A"A,,3 A,, A,,2 B,,2 |
| "D"A,,3 =D,/2A,,/2 D,2 F,G, | "Gbm"_G,,3 _G,,/2E,,/2 _G,,2 _D,_G,, | "G"=G,,3 G,,/2E,,/2 G,,2 B,,=D, | "A"A,2 G,A, A,E, A,,2 |
| "Bm"B,,2 =C,B,,/2A,,/2 B,,2 A,,2 | "Gbm"_G,3 _G,/2=F,/2 _G,2 _D,2 | "G"=G,3 =D, G,2 A,2 | "D"[D3^G,3] D D2 B,/2C/2A,/2^C,/2=C,/2 |
| "Bm"B,,3 B,,/2A,,/2 B,,3 F,,/2E,,/2 | "Gbm"_G,,3 _G,, E,,/2_G,,3/2 A,,_D, | "G"=G,,3 G,,/2E,,/2 G,,2 B,,/2G,,/2_B,,/2^G,,/2 | "A"A,,3 A,, A,,A,,=B,,C, |
| "D"D,3 D,/2A,,/2 D,2 A,2 | "Gbm"_G,,3 _G,,/2=F,,/2 _G,,3 E,, | "G"=G,,3 G,,/2E,,/2 G,,2 B,,3/2=C,/2 | "A"A,,4  z4 |
| "D" z3/2 B,,/2 ^C,D, A,,/2D,3/2- D,3/2A,/2 | "Gbm"_G,,3 _G,, E,,/2_G,,3/2 A,,_D, | "G"=G,,3 G,,/2E,,/2 G,,2 _B,,=D, | "A"A,,3 A,, A,,2 E,,2 |
| "Bm"B,2 B,2 [B,3D,3] F, | "Gbm"_G,,3 _G,,/2E,,/2 _G,,2 _D,_G,, | "G"=G,,3 G,,/2E,,/2 G,,2 =B,,[=D,A,,-- ] | "D"[D,3A,,3] D,  z4 |
| "Bm" z4  z2  z F,/2=F,/2 | "E"E,,3 E,, E,,2 B,,E,,/2G,,/2- | "G"G,,2- G,,/2G,,E,,/2 G,,3/2B,,/2- B,,2 | "G"_A,/2G,3/2 B,G, "A"=A,2 A,,2 |
| "D" z8 | "Gbm" z8 |
```

after it has been formatted it is pasted into the Java app Impro-Visor to give the chords.

Answer (score 4):

Use a global (`g`), multi-line (`m`) [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) to match any pipe (`\|`) at the start of a line (`^`)

```js
// here's your original string
let tOut = `| D| Gbm| G| A|
| D| Gbm| G| A|
| Bm| Gbm| G| D|
| Bm| Gbm| G| A|
| D| Gbm| G| A|
| D| Gbm| G| A|
| Bm| Gbm| G| D|
| Bm| E| G| G A|
| D| Gbm|`

// replace the pipes
tOut = tOut.replace(/^\| ?/mg, '')

console.log(tOut)
// document.write(tOut)
```

The above also removes the space following the pipe if it's present. If you want to keep the space, change the regex to `/^\|/mg`.

Comment: Yeah, that's a better idea.

Comment: Where do I put it in ```view-source:http://www.lesession.co.uk/abc/abcChordsOut.htm``` for ```document.write(tOut)```

Comment: @LuaStart I've updated my answer to try and make it a little clearer

Comment: I saved the page from that website and running it locally, I inserted the 2 lines above ```// document.write(tOut)``` but I don't get the results. If you paste that ABC code into the offline page you will see what it does.

Answer (score 1):

You can [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the multiline string on the line break (`\n`), use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to remove the first character from each line, and [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) on the line break to convert the array back to a string. This works no matter what character each line starts with.

```js
const str = `| D| Gbm| G| A|
| D| Gbm| G| A|
| Bm| Gbm| G| D|
| Bm| Gbm| G| A|
| D| Gbm| G| A|
| D| Gbm| G| A|
| Bm| Gbm| G| D|
| Bm| E| G| G A|
| D| Gbm|`;
const res = str.split("\n").map(s=>s.slice(1)).join("\n");
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the changed code that worked, prevent line break, remove the ":::|" and replaced "||" with "|"br""

```
tOut += "" //"<br>"

tOut = tOut.split(":::|").join("");
tOut = tOut.split("||").join("|<br>");
document.write(tOut)
```